# Can a JSP know if it is inside an iFrame or not?

Tags: jsp, iframe

For a variety of reasons I need a JSP to act and display differently depending on whether it is being viewed as a parent page or if it is being viewed via an iFrame.

Is there a way for the JSP to know how it is being displayed so that it acts correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSP can't figure out whether it's in a frame. But you maybe you could use javascript. Here's a very simple javascript call that will detect whether you're in a frame:

```
if(top != self) {
    alert("In an HTML frame");
}
```

If you need to know whether you're in a frame on the server side, then maybe you could do something like

1. Add small bit of javascript to jsp to detect whether it's in a frame
2. Send the result of whether you're in a frame back to servlet via ajax call
3. Store the result in the session in the servlet.

Comment: That worked a treat, we don't need to do this at the server end, just have a slightly different look and feel when displayed.